# How can I add Jcombobox on the image set by me in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to add a combobox on the image set by me.I have tried LayeredPane also,but could not have the desired result. Plzz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to add a combobox on the image set by me

You can set the layout manager of any Swing component.

So if you are displaying your image in a JLabel you can set the layout of the label. For example:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem(...);
background.add( comboBox );
```

If you are painting the image on the JPanel, the default layout is already a FlowLayout, you just need to override the `getPreferredsize()` method of the panel to be the size of the image.